# How to include a javascript from /js/ in jekyll

Tags: javascript, jekyll

I've added the cookie consent code from [here](https://jekyllcodex.org/without-plugin/cookie-consent/)

It has

```
<script>
...
if(readCookie('cookie-notice-dismissed')=='true') {
    {% include ga.js %}
    {% include chatbutton.js %}
}
...
</script>
```

in the html. This is placed within `_includes` but I can't figure out how to include javascript like `/js/foo.js`, located in another directory. I believe this is bundled with bundler within the jekyll assets.

Up to now, I've added javascript on my layouts in the following way, but haven't used `{% include %}` for this yet and I don't know how to let the `_includes/cookie_consent.html` know ẁhere to find it.

```
<script src="/js/foo.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        new Foo(".js-foo");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two options to solve this

1. you create a file in `_includes` that contains the links to the extra JS you want.
   For example:

```
# /_includes/bar.html
<script src="/js/foo.js"><\/script>
```

Inside `_cookie_consent.html` you can then add`{% include bar.html %}`

2. You add the link directly to your body.

```js
if(readCookie('cookie-notice-dismissed')=='true') {
    const js = '<script src="/js/foo.js"></script>'
    document.body.appendChild(js)
}
```

Comment: I use a similar method as above, basically I modify my `_config.yml` so that `includes_dir: ./src` and then I store all of my partials, and compiled css and js in sub-directories of `src`. You can then include them like `{% include js/foo.js %}` in your templates.  As an aside, this method is useful if you are building an AMP site, since you need to include your CSS in your document head..

Comment: Mh... none of the two options worked; the included javascript was displayed as a string not script code. Probably because the readCookie snippet is itself between <script> tags, so you end up with nested script tags. The include should include the javascript verbatim without adding any tags, I guess.

Comment: Ah, I had to change `</script>` to `<\/script>`. Otherwise it was closing the script tag prematurely. Added this and the semicolons and seems to work. Excellent! I'd suggest you add this to your snippet?

Comment: @quimnuss This is for the first option right? I've updated my snippet

Comment: @RobbeVP The second one. On the first one you get a syntax error, `expected expression got <` either way; it's putting script html tags in the cookie_consent javascript code.